# Chai.js - How do I test if JSX component has specific style property?

Tags: javascript, testing, chai, preact

## The problem:


I created a generic button component using preact.js lib. I also created a prop that turn the button centered or align left:

- `button.js`

  ```
  import { h } from 'preact';
  import style from './style.less';
  import Button from '../button/index';

  const Button = (props) => (
      <div style={{textAlign: `${props.isCentered ? "center" : "left"}`}}>
      <a style={{backgroundColor: `${props.bgColor}`, color: `${props.color}`}} class={style.a}>{props.text}</a>
      </div>
  );

  export default Button;
  ```

In my testes suit I was thinking about a way to check if the button component is centered or not. But I do not want to compare the entire component itself, because the test can break for other reason than the property `align: center` or `align: left`:

- `button.test.js`

  ```
  import { h } from 'preact';
  import { expect } from 'chai';

  import Button from '../../../src/components/button';

  describe('components/Header', () => {

      const buttonCentered = <Button isCentered={true} text="Precisa de alguma ajuda?" bgColor="#673ab7" color="white" />;
      const buttonNotCentered = <Button isCentered={false} text="Precisa de alguma ajuda?" bgColor="#673ab7" color="white" />;

      const buttonWithNoText = <Button isCentered={false} text=" " bgColor="#673ab7" color="white" />;

      it('should show button centered', () => {
          expect(buttonCentered).to.equal(
              <div style="text-align: center;">
                  <a class="a" style="background-color: #673ab7; color: white;">Precisa de alguma ajuda?</a>
              </div>
          );
      });

      it('should show button not centered', () => {
          expect(buttonNotCentered).to.equal(
              <div style="text-align: left;">
                  <a class="a" style="background-color: #673ab7; color: white;">Precisa de alguma ajuda?</a>
              </div>
          );
      });
  });
  ```

So my questions is: How do I check if the component has the specific style `align: center` or `align: left` usign the chai.js assertions api?

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but it looks like you should be able to access `buttonCentered.props.isCentered`.

Comment: Yeah but, I want to test the html code that was created by the component. Using `buttonCentered.props.isCentered` I test if my prop has certain property, but not if that generated a html element with centered align

Comment: What do you get when you `console.log(buttonCentered)`?

Comment: @ChrisG got it:

`VNode {
        nodeName: [Function: Button],
        children: [],
        attributes: 
         { isCentered: true,
           text: 'Precisa de alguma ajuda?',
           bgColor: '#673ab7',
           color: 'white' },
        key: undefined }`

Comment: Alright, that doesn't help, I guess. Looks like you need a way to render the element server-side, so you're able to check the resulting DOM element.

Comment: Yeah, I think that you are right. The best way is to get the html generated for the component and after that check the align property. But I still do not know how kind of assert from chai api I use for that.